# Call Pytest as a Subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I want to call pytest from a python function. I am able to make it work with `os.system`. I would like to use a sub process to retrieve the pytest output.

```
cmd = ["pytest", "-s", debug, "DeviceTests/{0}".format(test_name), "--device_id {0}".format(device_address), "--firmware_version {0}".format(firmware_version)]
print(cmd)
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()
print(out)
```

The subprocess does run but tells me there is an error. My pytest requires two CLI options. Running the subprocess I am told the two CLI options are not present.

Here is my cmd and the error.

```
Running Test DisioOnBACnetTest
['pytest', '-s', '--disable-pytest-warnings', 'DeviceTests/DisioOnBACnetTest', '--device_id 9101', '--firmware_version 0.1.1']
b''
b'ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]\npytest: error: the following arguments are required: --device_id, --firmware_version\n\n'
```

As you can see I am sending the device_id and firmware_version but the sub process is not properly sending them to pytest.

Comment: off subject, but if you are in python3 you can just say things like `f"DeviceTests/{test_name}"`

Comment: Does that give the output of the script as well?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Was just pointing out that expressions like `"DeviceTests/{0}".format(test_name)` can now be written like `f"DeviceTests/{test_name}"`. Which is easier and more compact.

Comment: I see, you are talking about formatting the string. I though you were saying I could call a script that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly separate the arguments.

This:

```
"--device_id {0}".format(device_address), "--firmware_version {0}".format(firmware_version)
```

should be

```
"--device_id", "{0}".format(device_address), "--firmware_version", "{0}".format(firmware_version)
```

Comment: I updated my cmd in the original post. I get the same issue, nothing is run.

Comment: @Michael --device_id and 9101 need to be TWO separate arguments (their own string, not in one combined string!!), the same for --firmware_version and 0.1.1